# Install additional software for eclipse ganymede

Tags: eclipse, ganymede

for some reason, i must use old version of eclipse Ganymede for developing. When install, it just has JDT for programming java.  I want to add CDT for programming C. But I don't know update site of this version. I have tried this link:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ganymede
```

But this link won't help. Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Your link misspells "ganymede"?  BETTER CHOICE: There's always good old "vi" and "make" :)  PS: Try this link: http://www.eclipse.org/ganymede/

Comment: @paulsm4 sorry, that my typos . I have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by myself. Instead install from eclipse, you can install from terminal.

```
su
// typing your root password here
yum install eclipse-cdt
```

And this method will work not only for this version but all others. Hope this will help many others.